# set font to ButtonRectangle View in MaterialDesignLibrary

Tags: android, material-design

I am using `MaterialDesignLibrary`. now, I would like to set my font to ButtonRectangle View. how can I do ?

```
        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
            android:id="@+id/my_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/color_default_buy_a_item"                    
            android:text="my btn"
             />
```

--

```
my_btn.setTypeface(font);
```

> The method setTypeface(Typeface) is undefined for the type
> ButtonRectangle

https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Answer (score 1):

Most of the views in [MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) are custom views.  In this case, the `TextView` internal to the custom view is exposed by `getTextView()`.  So:

`((ButtonRectangle) findViewById(R.id.my_btn)).getTextView().setTypeface(font);`

Answer (score 0):

**THIS ANSWER IS TEMPORARY. A BUGFIX IS POSSIBLE ON THE ORIGNAL REPOSITORY**

I think you might want to check this out. First, extend the ButtonRectangle and next find and change its associated textview.

```
public class FFButtonRectangle extends ButtonRectangle {
    public FFButtonRectangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TextView textView = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
        textView.setTypeFace(/** set your own type face instance here **/);
    }
}
```